# C: Bit fields and bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

My professor has assigned us some homework which uses bit fields, and has given us three macros

```
# define SETBIT(A, k) { A[k >> 3] |= (01 << (k & 07)); }
# define CLRBIT(A, k) { A[k >> 3] &= ~(01 << (k & 07)); }
# define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
```

which we're not required/expected to fully understand, only to use to complete the assignment. Each of these macros takes an `unsigned int` and and index (0-8) and sets/gets/clears a bit at that index. I get this and I get how to use it.

What I want to know is exactly what each of these macros does. Can somebody explain this to me like I'm five?

Comment: If you know what the `>>` and `<<` bit-shift operations do, how bitwise `&` and `|` work, and that the `x op= y` is shorthand for `x = x op y`, you can figure this out for yourself by working thru some examples. Try k==7 and k==8... Hints: A is an array of 8-bit bytes,  right-shifting by three is the same as dividing by 8, and the binary representation of 7 is 00000111.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What the macros do

Ignoring the problems outlined in the next section, the macros treat an array of an integral type as an array of 8-bit values, and when asked to work on bit `k`, processes the `k%8`<sup>th</sup> bit of the `k/8`<sup>th</sup> element of the array.

However, rather than using `k % 8` or `k / 8`, it uses shifts and masking.

```
# define SETBIT(A, k) { A[k >> 3] |= (01 << (k & 07)); }
# define CLRBIT(A, k) { A[k >> 3] &= ~(01 << (k & 07)); }
# define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
```

- `k >> 3` shifts a value right by 3 bit positions, effectively dividing by 8.
- `k & 07` extracts the 3 least significant bits (because `07` octal or `7` decimal is `111` in binary), ignoring the rest.
- The `01 << (k & 07)` shifts the value 1 left by 0..7 bits depending on the value of `k & 07`, producing one of the binary values:

  ```
  0000 0001
  0000 0010
  0000 0100
  0000 1000
  0001 0000
  0010 0000
  0100 0000
  1000 0000
  ```

  Formally, it is actually an `int` value, and hence probably has 32 bits, but the high order bits are all zeros.
- The `~` operator converts each 0 bit into a 1 and each 1 bit into a 0.
- The `&` operator combines two values, yielding a 1 bit where both bits are 1 and a 0 where either or both bits are 0.
- The `|` operator combines two values, yielding a 0 bit where both bits are 0 and a 1 where either or both bits are 1.
- The assignment operators `|=` and `&=` apply the operand on the RHS to the variable on the LHS.  The notation `a |= b;` is equivalent to `a = a | b;` except that `a` is evaluated just once.  This detail doesn't matter here; it matters intensely if there is an increment or something similar in the expression `a`.

Putting it all together:

- `SETBIT` sets the `k`<sup>th</sup> bit (meaning sets it to 1) in the array of 8-bit values represented by `A`.
- `CLRBIT` resets the `k`<sup>th</sup> bit (meaning sets it to 0) in the array of 8-bit values represented by `A`.
- `GETBIT` finds the value in the `k`<sup>th</sup> bit in the array of 8-bit values represented by `A`, and returns it as either `0` or `1` — that's what the final `>> (k & 07)` does.

Nominally, the array elements should be `unsigned char` to avoid problems with values and wasted space, but any integral type could be used, more or less wastefully.  You'd get interesting results if the type is `signed char` and the high bits are set on the values, or if the type is plain `char` and plain `char` is a signed type.  You could also get interesting results from `GETBIT` if the type of `A` is an integer type bigger than `char` and the values in the array have bits set outside the last (least significant) 8 bits of the number.

## What the macros do not do

The macros provided by the professor are an object lesson in how not to write C preprocessor macros.  They do not teach you how to write good C; they teach how to write appallingly awful C.

Each of those macros is dangerously broken because the argument `k` is not wrapped in parentheses when used.  It isn't hard to argue that the same applies to `A` too.  The use of `01` and `07` isn't exactly wrong, but octal `01` and `07` are the same as decimal `1` and `7`.

The `GETBIT` macro needs an extra level of parentheses around its whole body, too. Given

```
int y = 2;
unsigned char array[32] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234";
```

then this does not compile:

```
int x = GETBIT(array + 3, y + 2) + 13;
```

This does compile (with warnings) if your compiler options are lax enough, but would produce an eccentric result:

```
int x = GETBIT(3 + array, y + 2) + 13;
```

and that's before we try discussing:

```
int x = GETBIT(3 + array, y++) + 13;
```

The CLRBIT and SETBIT macros use braces which means that you can't write:

```
if (GETBIT(array, 13))
    SETBIT(array, 27);
else
    CLRBIT(array, 19);
```

because the semicolon after `SETBIT` is a null statement after the close brace in the statement block introduced by `SETBIT`, so the `else` clause is simply syntactically incorrect.

The macros could be written like this (retaining the statement block structure for the `SETBIT` and `CLRBIT` macros):

```
#define SETBIT(A, k) do { (A)[(k) >> 3] |= (1 << ((k) & 7)); } while (0)
#define CLRBIT(A, k) do { (A)[(k) >> 3] &= ~(1 << ((k) & 7)); } while (0)
#define GETBIT(A, k) (((A)[(k) >> 3] & (1 << ((k) & 7))) >> ((k) & 7))
```

The `do { … } while (0)` notation is a standard technique in macros that gets around the problem of breaking `if` / `else` statements.

The macros could also be rewritten like this because assignments are expressions:

```
#define SETBIT(A, k) ( (A)[(k) >> 3] |=  (1 << ((k) & 7)))
#define CLRBIT(A, k) ( (A)[(k) >> 3] &= ~(1 << ((k) & 7)))
#define GETBIT(A, k) (((A)[(k) >> 3] &   (1 << ((k) & 7))) >> ((k) & 7))
```

Or, even better, as `static inline` functions like this:

```
static inline void SETBIT(unsigned char *A, int k) { A[k >> 3] |=  (1 << (k & 7)); }
static inline void CLRBIT(unsigned char *A, int k) { A[k >> 3] &= ~(1 << (k & 7)); }
static inline int  GETBIT(unsigned char *A, int k) { return (A[k >> 3] & (1 << (k & 7))) >> (k & 7); }
```

The whole can be assembled into a simple test program:

```
#if MODE == 1

/* As provided */
#define SETBIT(A, k) { A[k >> 3] |= (01 << (k & 07)); }
#define CLRBIT(A, k) { A[k >> 3] &= ~(01 << (k & 07)); }
#define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)

#elif MODE == 2

/* As rewritten */
#define SETBIT(A, k) do { (A)[(k) >> 3] |= (1 << ((k) & 7)); } while (0)
#define CLRBIT(A, k) do { (A)[(k) >> 3] &= ~(1 << ((k) & 7)); } while (0)
#define GETBIT(A, k) (((A)[(k) >> 3] & (1 << ((k) & 7))) >> ((k) & 7))

#else

/* As rewritten */
static inline void SETBIT(unsigned char *A, int k) { A[k >> 3] |=  (1 << (k & 7)); }
static inline void CLRBIT(unsigned char *A, int k) { A[k >> 3] &= ~(1 << (k & 7)); }
static inline int  GETBIT(unsigned char *A, int k) { return (A[k >> 3] & (1 << (k & 7))) >> (k & 7); }

#endif

int main(void)
{
    int y = 2;
    unsigned char array[32] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234";
    int x = GETBIT(array + 3, y + 2) + 13;
    int z = GETBIT(3 + array, y + 2) + 13;

    if (GETBIT(array, 3))
        SETBIT(array, 22);
    else
        CLRBIT(array, 27);

    return x + z;
}
```

When compiled with `-DMODE=2` or `-DMODE=0` or without any `-DMODE` setting, then it is clean.  When compiled with `-DMODE=1`, there are an objectionable number of warnings (errors for me because I use GCC and compile with `-Werror` which makes any warning into an error).

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -DMODE=0 bits23.c -o bits23 
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -DMODE=2 bits23.c -o bits23
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -DMODE=1 bits23.c -o bits23
bits23.c: In function ‘main’:
bits23.c:28:33: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ inside ‘>>’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int x = GETBIT(array + 3, y + 2) + 13;
                                 ^
bits23.c:6:25: note: in definition of macro ‘GETBIT’
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                         ^
bits23.c:6:24: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                        ^
bits23.c:28:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘GETBIT’
     int x = GETBIT(array + 3, y + 2) + 13;
             ^
bits23.c:28:33: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ in operand of ‘&’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int x = GETBIT(array + 3, y + 2) + 13;
                                 ^
bits23.c:6:43: note: in definition of macro ‘GETBIT’
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                                           ^
bits23.c:28:33: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ in operand of ‘&’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int x = GETBIT(array + 3, y + 2) + 13;
                                 ^
bits23.c:6:57: note: in definition of macro ‘GETBIT’
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                                                         ^
bits23.c:29:33: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ inside ‘>>’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int z = GETBIT(3 + array, y + 2) + 13;
                                 ^
bits23.c:6:25: note: in definition of macro ‘GETBIT’
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                         ^
bits23.c:29:33: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ in operand of ‘&’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int z = GETBIT(3 + array, y + 2) + 13;
                                 ^
bits23.c:6:43: note: in definition of macro ‘GETBIT’
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                                           ^
bits23.c:29:22: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ in operand of ‘&’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int z = GETBIT(3 + array, y + 2) + 13;
                      ^
bits23.c:6:23: note: in definition of macro ‘GETBIT’
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                       ^
bits23.c:29:33: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ in operand of ‘&’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int z = GETBIT(3 + array, y + 2) + 13;
                                 ^
bits23.c:6:57: note: in definition of macro ‘GETBIT’
 #define GETBIT(A, k) (A[k >> 3] & (01 << (k & 07))) >> (k & 07)
                                                         ^
bits23.c:29:38: error: suggest parentheses around ‘+’ inside ‘>>’ [-Werror=parentheses]
     int z = GETBIT(3 + array, y + 2) + 13;
                                      ^
bits23.c:33:5: error: ‘else’ without a previous ‘if’
     else
     ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed explanation, and especially for explaining why this is not the best practice and how it could be improved! Seriously, wish I could up-vote twice.